# Installed magento extension Ma2_Manufacturers_Free but it doesn't appear in admin area

Tags: magento

I'm installed magento extension successfully but it doesn't appear at admin area. I install via magento connect from this magento developer:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer/Magen_Market

Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: clear your cache, reindex all, then log out and login again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when ever you install a extension. Do the following steps

> 1.clear your magento cache
>
> 2.reindex all.
>
> 3.logout from admin panel and login again.